# ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT al abrir archivo local

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

obtengo la direccion de de la base de datos y quiero cargar el pdf que esta en esa direccion pero aparece este error 
Response.Redirect("C:\archivo.pdf");
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El/los archivo(s) pdf necesita(n) estar en los directorios de tu aplicación web. Puede ser en el directorio principal de tu app, o en algún folder especifico para los archivos pdf (recomiendo esta segunda opción).

Si acaso son archivos que son fijos, y ya están en tu proyecto/solución de Visual Studio, no olvides marcarlos como archivos de contenido y que sean copiados ya sea 'siempre' o 'si son nuevos'.

[image: Propiedades de archivo]